# curl gives me a blank page on yahoo.co.jp

Tags: php, curl

I try to get the seller name from a page of Yahoo Japan auction, it worked well up to 1 year ago and then it suddenly stopped working.

the code below is for the moment just to be able to get the auction page.
I will use pregmatch after to get the information I need.

Any help would be more than welcomed, I've been searching for monthes without any solution yet. Thank you in advance.

```
    <html>
    <head><title>Get info</title>
    <!--meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/plain;charset=utf-8"/-->
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
    $link="https://page.auctions.yahoo.co.jp/jp/auction/c713387584";
    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0)         Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0";

    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt"); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

        $result = curl_exec ($curl);
        curl_close ($curl);
        print $result;


        fclose($fp);

    unlink("cookie.txt");
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

`

Comment: Maybe you should check for error messages on the `$curl` object and add them to your question?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem is there is no error message and this code works perfectly fine with others sites.

Comment: Nothing from [curl_error()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)?

Comment: Exact - I added the code of curl_error() after the "$result = curl_exec ($curl);" but it doesn't return anything. And as I said just above, it works perfectly fine with https://stackoverflow.com by example.

Comment: I tried on the command line `curl --verbose >/dev/null --cookie-jar dummy.txt --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0' https://page.auctions.yahoo.co.jp/jp/auction/c713387584`. I see a successful TLS/HTTP handshake and receive about 105K of data. If that fails on your host, then I think the problem is not PHP or curl but something else.

Comment: here what I got with the verbose test (curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);) :
Verbose information:

* About to connect() to page.auctions.yahoo.co.jp port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 183.79.217.124... * connected
* Connected to page.auctions.yahoo.co.jp (183.79.217.124) port 443 (#0)
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to page.auctions.yahoo.co.jp:443 
* Closing connection #0

Comment: Have you checked if your curl/openssl is maybe too old? If I add to the mentioned command line `--tls-max 1.0` or `--tls-max 1.1` the connection is refused. I.e. the server only accepts clients that speak at least TLS 1.2.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use scripted, headless browser / web automation framework such as PhantomJS and Selenium WebDriver to avoid TLS errors, as the software / framework mimics a user browsing a website while crawling the elements in the page.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your problem is caused by too old curl/openssl (or whatever SSL backend your curl is compiled with).

This is what I get from the command line:

```
$ curl --silent --verbose >/dev/null --http1.1 --tls-max 1.1 --cookie-jar dummy.txt https://page.auctions.yahoo.co.jp/jp/auction/c713387
*   Trying 183.79.250.251...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to page.auctions.yahoo.co.jp (183.79.250.251) port 443 (#0)
...
* TLSv1.1 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [148 bytes data]
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to page.auctions.yahoo.co.jp:443 
* Closing connection 0

$ curl --silent --verbose >/dev/null --http1.1 --tls-max 1.2 --cookie-jar dummy.txt https://page.auctions.yahoo.co.jp/jp/auction/c713387 
*   Trying 183.79.250.251...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to page.auctions.yahoo.co.jp (183.79.250.251) port 443 (#0)
...
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
...
* Connection #0 to host page.auctions.yahoo.co.jp left intact
```

Compare this to SO:

```
$ curl --silent --verbose >/dev/null --http1.1 --tls-max 1.1 https://stackoverflow.com/  
*   Trying 151.101.65.69...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to stackoverflow.com (151.101.65.69) port 443 (#0)
...
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
...
* Connection #0 to host stackoverflow.com left intact
```

In short: yahoo.co.jp only accepts clients that speak at least TLS 1.2, SO allows older clients.

Comment: Sorry for the time to answer, I had some difficulties to upgrade php and so on, but it should be fine now. Trouble is that it hasn't changed anything ^^; Moreover, I tried to go back to the basic with a simple html iframe, and it gives me a blank iframe.

Comment: As I tried to explain in my answer: as long as you are not checking (a) what SSL backend your PHP/curl has been compiled with and (b) if that SSL backend supports TLS 1.2 or newer, you won't make any progress.

Comment: I don't knoe why but suddenly my former code was unable to do what it has done perfectly up to now and with this simplified code and a new php / curl, it works perfectly.
Just in case of, I write it down :
    <?php
    $url="https://page.auctions.yahoo.co.jp/jp/auction/c713387584";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $data;
    ?>